# What is a good mechanics book without calculus

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I am very interested in physics and I want to improve my basics especially in mechanics.
I have only started high school (junior) so I don't know much about calculus, which is used in most of the books.
I am only looking for a conceptual books explained basic concepts nicely.

Comment: You can't really get anywhere without calculus in physics. I suggest you start by studying the prerequisite math before trying to dive into physics too deeply.

Comment: Any high school textbook. I'm not sure if the symplectic geometry approach uses calculus, but it's obviously not what you are looking for.